# Laravel events and Pest test

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, laravel-10

What I am doing is I add an extra `online` column to the default `User` model in Laravel. It's a boolean value, and I update it every time when the user login or logout. Currently I am listening for the `LogSuccessfulLogin` event, and handle it when this event apper, like this

```
EventServiceProvider.php

protected $listen = [
    Registered::class => [
        SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
    ],
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogSuccessfulLogin',
    ],
];


public function handle(Login $event): void
{ 
   $event->user->online = 1;
   $event->user->save();
}
```

And I am learning `Pest` so I try to write a test for it.

```
test('users online status is updating during login', function() {
$user = User::factory()->create();

$this->post('/login', [
    'email' => $user->email,
    'password' => 'password',
]);

$this->assertTrue($user->online);
```

});

If I check it manually the `online` column is updated  well, but the test fail. I think it's because the event, and the test just don't wait for the event to update the `online` value. How can I tell to the test to wait for the event to end.

I am very new to Pest, so maybe this is not the problem, any help would be appreciated